# Why transparent background doesn't work with GD?

Tags: php, gd

I'm creating image with PHP library GD:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('http://polariton.ad-l.ink/8rRSf4CpN/thumb.png');
$w = imagesx($image);
$h = imagesy($image);

$border = imagecreatefrompng('https://www.w3schools.com/css/border.png');

// New border width

$x1 = $w;
$x2 = 28;
$x3 = (int)($x1 / $x2);
$x4 = $x1 - $x3 * $x2;
$x5 = $x4 / $x3;
$x2 = $x2 + $x5;

$bw = $x2;

// New border height

$y1 = $h;
$y2 = 28;
$y3 = (int)($y1 / $y2);
$y4 = $y1 - $y3 * $y2;
$y5 = $y4 / $y3;
$y2 = $y2 + $y5;

$bh = $y2;

// New image width and height

$newWidth = (int)$w * (1 - ((($bw * 100) / (int)$w) / 100 * 2));
$newHeight = (int)$h * (1 - ((($bh * 100) / (int)$h) / 100 * 2));

// Transparent border

$indent = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($indent, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($indent, 0, 0, $color);

imagecopyresampled($indent, $image, $bw, $bw, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $w, $h);

// Vertical border

$verticalX = 0;
$verticalY = $bh;

while ($verticalY < $h - $bh) {
    // Left
    imagecopy($indent, $border, $verticalX, $verticalY, 0, 27, $bh, $bh);

    // Right
    imagecopy($indent, $border, $w - $bw, $verticalY, 0, 27, $bh, $bh);

    $verticalY += $bh;
}

// Horizontal border

$horizontalX = $bw;
$horizontalY = 0;

while ($horizontalX < $w - $bw) {
    // Top
    imagecopy($indent, $border, $horizontalX, $horizontalY, 0, 27, $bw, $bw);

    // Bottom
    imagecopy($indent, $border, $horizontalX, $h - $bh, 0, 27, $bw, $bw);

    $horizontalX += $bw;
}

// Left top border
imagecopy($indent, $border, 0, 0, 0, 0, $bw, $bh);

// Right top border
imagecopy($indent, $border, $w - $bw, 0, 0, 0, $bw, $bh);

// Right bottom border
imagecopy($indent, $border, $w - $bw, $h - $bh, 0, 0, $bw, $bh);

// Left bottom border
imagecopy($indent, $border, 0, $h - $bh, 0, 0, $bw, $bh);


// Save result

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($indent);
```

But transparency does't work:
[image]

Idk why, I do everything as written in the documentation.

What could be the problem?

Comment: JPEG files don't support transparency.

Comment: Ok. I changed image on PNG and changed imagecreatefromjpeg to imagecreatefrompng, and imagejpeg($indent, null, 100) to imagepng($indent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG files don't support transparency.

You can try a different format, for example PNG.

You'll need to make a small change to your code to enable the output to maintain alpha-channel transparency by calling `imagesavealpha` just after you create your new image resource:

```
...
$indent = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagesavealpha($indent, true);
...
```

And then change your last two lines:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($indent);
```